# mat2gray function does not work when called from Perl

Tags: perl, octave

I have a script in perl that generates a .m file based on a series of parameters and then runs an octave algorithm through ticks like:

```
`octave my_script`;
```

And then I capture the results in a separate file. The problem is that even having installed the image package succesfuly mat2gray function is not working. 
If I open manually octave like a separate console to be used manually, and call my script it does work perfectly. The issue appears only when calling the octave.exe from Perl. It shows:

```
error: `mat2gray' undefined near line 21 column 6
```

Which looks like the typical error you get when you don't have the image package (and I do have it installed and I'm able to usethe function on octave console directly). I already tried to iclude a line on my script at the very top to rebuild the package everytime my script runs, like so:

```
pkg rebuild -auto image;
```

But that didn't fix it. Anyone has seen this kind of odd behavior?

I'm using Octave 3.2.4, since I need that version due to some compatibility issues with other pieces of software that we need. And some plotting capabilities when called from perl don't work all that well. Just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I replied to the question [here](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/mat2gray-not-working-when-called-from-Perl-only-console-td4647513.html).